# Using Codeigniter in Zf2

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework2

I have an project that is used by many users and it's written in Codeigniter. I'm very happy with my application but I'm getting lost with Codeigniter because of the functionality of the framework and my application is getting too big for Codeigniter (that is what I think).

I want to go from Codeigniter to Zend, but the application is too big to begin all over again because there is still more functionality to come.

I don't know if someone has experienced or tried it, but does anybody know if it is possible to integrate Codeigniter into Zend as an module and migrate in steps to the Zend Framework 2?

Sorry for my bad english by the way :-)

Comment: And how do you think that you will be able to share the session states/information?

Answer (score 1):

Having experience with small and medium-scale projects with both CodeIgniter (CI) and Zend Framework (ZF), I can tell you that using one framework over the other will not solve any problem you might be having.

If you are looking for the added functionality provided by the ZF components, such as a ready-made class for Date or the Form verification class, know that you can use ZF components in Code Igniter. You will need to create a special class in CI that will jumpstart the ZF class autoloader. From there you can simply `include` ZF classes and use them as if you were inside a ZF application.

See http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/21/using-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/ and http://fr.slideshare.net/samsonasik/codeigniter-using-third-party-components-zend-framework-components for more details.

Comment: I want to move to Zend Framework 2 because I really like the autoloading, Structure from namespaces and the better structure of classes (because the independence injection, servicelocator etc.). I don't know if you have any experience with Zf2, but I worked with it for an other project and found out that Zf2 is more flexible. What do you think about my opinion?

Comment: I find Zend Framework more restrictive. You need to name your classes and files in exactly the good way otherwise it will not autoload them. Also, I find ZF to be more bloated than CI, adding milliseconds where it shouldn't.

I totally agree that ZF feels much more structured than CI though, and the list of options (Zend Services and whatnot) is much larger in ZF than CI. Then again, ZF projects always seem so **complicated** compared to CI ones.

Answer (score 0):

"Integrate" means you want to put your **app running on CodeIgniter** withing ZendFramework. So basically you changed nothing and there's no much sense of doing so.

You perhaps could consider **porting** your app from CI to ZF, but that will require rewriting of your code. But I'd first try to find out what the bottleneck in your app really is and ensure that you will benefit from the switch

Comment: I want to move it to Zend Framework because I can go further with my production and also port it to Zend Framework. So every new function I try to code it in Zend Framework and the old functionality are still in the old Codeigniter project.